# Ubuntu Wubi "drive" failure; mount drive in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, ntfs, ext3, wubi

I installed the Wubi distribution of Ubuntu on a separate partition (which is silly, since why do I care if Windows can still manage the partition?) a few months back; it was pretty awesome, until Linux hosed. At this point, I can get Ubuntu to boot if I try really hard through grub, but once it does start, the screen is hosed, so no dice. At this point, I'd like to wipe it all and start over, but I need to get some stuff off the "disk".

The Wubi install makes this difficult, since the "disk" is a flat file on an NTFS partition. I've done just about everything I can think of — I renamed the virtual disk .iso, mounted it with VirtualCloneDrive, then used whatever magic EXT3 (EXT4?) readers I could dig up on the Internet to parse the mount — but nothing's working. Can you offer any suggestions?

The "disk" is currently in `D:\ubuntu\disks\root.iso`.

Many thanks!

(I may be high-latency at the moment, apologies if I don't address follow-ups quickly)

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1037874) on ubuntu's forums gives a tutorial on how to mount the disk from a Linux live CD or another Linux OS.

It could also possibly be done through Windows in CygWin (can't link since I am a new user on SU) but I would just stick with the live CD.

You do not have to create that script, in fact I would recommend doing it manually so that it's easier to debug.

Comment: cygwin won't help without a windows filesystem driver.  livecd is the right way to go, tho.

Comment: @quack quixote Cygwin can access Windows drives. It's built in. It's under /cygdrive: `# ls /cygdrive/ c  d  e  g  i`

Comment: yes, obviously.  but if windows can't access a partition because it doesn't have a filesystem driver for that filesystem (eg ext2/3/4, hfs+, etc), then cygwin won't access it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the image without mounting it - [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs).

Comment: Just tried it: no dice; I loaded up the disk image file, and it's empty. There are files somewhere on there... it would be nice if there were some sort of error messages.

Comment: @618034: That's strange. Maybe http://ext2fsd.com/ supports mounting files?